# How to stop ResizeEnd event when form is moved?

Tags: winforms

I write certain code in my form `ResizeEnd` event. Now problem is when form is moved by clicking and dragging on the caption bar, `ResizeEnd` event is fired and code is executed even though form size is NOT changed.

I gone through MSDN documentation for [`Resizeend`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.resizeend.aspx) event and it says that event will fire when form is moved (don't understand why this happens when the size is NOT changed).

For resolution I put the if condition to check if size is changed like below to stop execution of code on form move:

```
int Prv_Height; int Prv_Width;
private void TemplateGrid_ResizeEnd(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (this.Size.Width != Prv_Width || this.Size.Height != Prv_Height)
    {
        Prv_Width = this.Size.Width;
        Prv_Height = this.Size.Height;
        //Other code here when form resize ends...
    }
}
```

So is there any way to stop `ResizeEnd` event to fire when form is moved? or any other better approach to solve the problem?

Comment: Thanks for asking this, exactly my question too. The behavior of this event seems odd to me.

Comment: Consider the SizeChanged event instead.

Answer (score 0):

You could move your check for sizechange to a new baseform. On derived forms the resizeEnd event will then only fire if the size is actually changed.

```
public partial class CustomForm : Form
{                       
    private Size _prvSize;

    public CustomForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();        
    }

    protected override void OnShown(EventArgs e)
    {
        _prvSize = this.Size;
        base.OnShown(e);
    }

    protected override void OnResizeEnd(EventArgs e)
    {
        if (this.Size == _prvSize)
            return;

        _prvSize = this.Size;
        base.OnResizeEnd(e);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private void Form1_ResizeBegin(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
    oldSize = ClientSize;
 }
 private Size oldSize = new Size();
 private void Form1_ResizeEnd(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     if (oldSize == ClientSize)
        return;
    //Add Something
 }
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer.